# Iphone usage awareness

Tags: iphone, applications

Hi I´m an OT working in a high school in Iceland and we are doing a project on internet usage and how we use it in our lives. I have been looking for a app that lets my kids monitor their app usage time so that they can analyze how much time each day they spend on different apps such as Facebook, Instagram etc. I can´t find any for Iphone except a Cydia app (we can´t use that) but I found a great one for Android called App usage tracker which gives me exactly the info I need.  Does anybody have any ideas on similar apps for Iphone?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 9 or newer, you can head into Settings and then Battery on their iPhones for a list of all the apps that are using the students' batteries. Tap anywhere on the list of apps that appears in settings there to **reveal exactly how long each app has been open in the last 24 hours or the last 7 days.**

No need to install an app, no need to configure anything. Make sure you go into battery settings once on each phone before your trials begin so that it starts recording battery usage data per-app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iOS app called Hooked.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hooked-app-habit-tracker/id966290813?mt=8